# Run MPEG Dash bitrate adaptive streaming on WPF

Tags: wpf, mpeg-dash, dash.js

I've develop an html5 video player with dash.js that plays streaming mpeg dash content. It works great.

Now I have a requirement to run the same on WPF. using an webbrowser to run my already developed html5 sounds very dirty but I can't figure what I can use to make streaming work.

any tips?

Answer (score 1):

There exists no DASH player library for WPF that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

@Sander is right, there doesn't appear to be a WPF or C# Dash implementation at this point.

[Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn551368(v=vs.85).aspx) on building a player suggests using [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js)

I'm also not an expert with WPF and have no experience playing video of any kind within WPF. That said I assume you should be able to do something similar to the way dash.js works with the HTML5 Video element. This would require you to do a number of different tasks like parse the `MPD` file format, and download the required segment(s).

The simplest implementation of this would be simply parsing the `MPD` and finding one specific bitrate / resolution `BaseURL` and passing those values to a WPF element that can handle playing `mp4` files. However to really get the benefits of DASH you would need to fully parse the `MPD` file and implement logic around bitrate switching, etc.